# New development in variable selection in clustering using MCMC?

Tags: clustering, references, feature-selection, markov-chain-montecarlo

The latest general framework I know in MCMC-based wrapper method (doing variable selection and clustering simultaneously) are the paper "[Bayesian variable selection in clustering high-dimensional data](http://www18.georgetown.edu/data/people/mgt26/publication-29809.pdf)" of Tadesse et al (2005) and the paper "[Variable selection in clustering via Dirichlet process mixture models](http://www18.georgetown.edu/data/people/mgt26/publication-29804.pdf)" of Kim et al (2006).

I wonder if there are any new developments in this area?

In particular, has anyone tried to extend the model of Tadesse?